# MongoDB sort by $natural in php not working

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

I'm querying data from some collection, In my pipeline I have the stages : match, skip, limit. When i add the sort stage, I GET THE ERROR MESSAGE : mongodb fieldpath field names may not start with $. The code is like:`$collection->aggregate(array(
array('$match'=>$my_query),array('$limit'=>$my_limit),
array('skip'=>$my_skip),array('$sort'=>array('$natural'=>-1)))`

Comment: isn't it `$skip` and not `skip` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [mongo issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8131).

But, what does it mean to do a $natural sort at the end of the aggregation pipeline?

If it is ascending, well, that's the same as not having the sort at all. If descending, it means getting the results in a reverse order.

Comment: Should I put it at the beginning of the aggregation pipeline?